# Reducing the amount of data by extracting a representative sample of my population

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, sample-size, population

I have 6 B&W images representing different wavelengths (i.e. Landsat bands) of the Alta Valtellina (Italy). I extracted from the images only the areas of bare soil. Now, I want to perform a PCA on the pixels of these images (48128 pixels *6 bands) in MATLAB. My problem is that there are too many data to make visuale interpretation of the PC plots clear. Therefore, I'd like to reduce the amount of data so that the analysis result would be preserved as much as possible. Since this task probably requires knowledge on the distribution of the data, I might say the observations (i.e each pixel showing the 6 different values according to the different bands) are labelled as "rock glacier" and "not rock glacier". Since the number of "rock glacier" pixels is 2721, I confirmed the normality of the distribution of such pixels with the Shapiro-Wilk test, but I can't run the same test on the other "not rock glacier" pixels as their number is too high (45408 pixels).

I thought extracting the pixels from the 25th to the 75th percentiles would be a good idea, but doing so for each variable would let me forget about the observations (the range 25th–75th percentiles of one variable does not correspond than that of another variable). If the difference is great, the extraction would possibly not be representative of the original population.

In the light of such, does anybody have a suggestion on how should I reduce the number of pixels preserving the PCA result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just don't do this. There is no need to discard data at all. The only specific reason you've given for discarding data is that you can't apply a particular function to get a normality test, but you've given no reason why that test is of any use or interest. If graphs from the full dataset are unclear, there is no reason to suppose that they will be clearer if you discard much of the data.

Comment: More specifically, keeping the middle half of a distribution just does not qualify as a representative sample.

Comment: The Shapiro-Wilks test is intended for testing whether the distribution of *independent* observations is Gaussian; yours are spatially correlated.

Comment: Exact Normality is rare: Hampel et al.(1986, pp 22-23) cites analysts, starting with Bessel, 1818, who studied "very high quality" data sets. Most were longer-tailed than normal and were well-approximated by t-distributions with 3-9 d.f. 
; skewness was also present. **Reference**: Frank Hampel, Elvezio Ronchetti, Peter Rousseeuw, and Werner Stahel.
1986. Robust Statistics: The Approach Based on Influence Functions (Wiley Series in Probability and Mathematical Statistics). New York:.